# Problem in unity, my faces disappear

Tags: modeling, unity

when i exporting my truck object or another from blender to unity some my faces disappear in unity. I add some images for better understanding.[image][image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O8FgM.png)

Comment: probably a face normal problem. Select vertices and ctrl+shift+n to recalculate normals.

Comment: I click and nothing happens

Answer (score 1):

Select all the offending mesh in edit mode and in Shading tab select Normals: "Flip Direction". Your model appears to be facing the wrong way, so when backface culling comes into play you can only see the inside. I hihgly recommend you press N in 3D view and enable Shading: Backface Culling.

Comment: Doesnt work, to be more specific if i look wheel from another side i can see this "empty face" but dont see first face as before. The visibility is "change" when i change perspective. and this is only in Unity ://